Launch an admin cmd.exe from Windows Explorer with current working directory = current Explorer folder
In Windows Explorer, I often do CTRL+L c m d ENTER to quickly launch a cmd.exe shell with the working directory being the current Explorer folder. It's a handy and quick 1-second shortcut. (I don't use Powershell, I prefer cmd.exe)
But then, the cmd.exe which is started is not admin, even though my current Windows user is Administrator.
Example: mklink .... gives You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation (see also: Why can't I make a symbolic link (mklink) even when I'm an administrator)
How to launch an (administrator) cmd.exe from a Windows Explorer window, with the current working directory = the current folder in Explorer?
Notes:

Some answers are given in Hotkey to open cmd with administration rights in current folder from Explorer but 1) it's off topic on SO 2) most answers don't give an admin cmd.exe 3) some do but  you end with an admin Powershell which I don't want  4) some are outdated and no longer work on newer Win10 versions (see comments).

Similar question but for Powershell: Open Powershell as Administrator at Current File Explorer Directory Keyboard Shortcut (Windows 10)



Put this as a.vbs into one of the front entries of %PATH% and do CTRL+L a . v b s ENTER  wherever you are.
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
currentDir = wshShell.CurrentDirectory
objShell.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/K chdir /D " & currentDir, "", "runas", 1

This is faster than powershell and independent of execution policies. By using .vbs no intermediate window is shown. Confirm the opening UAC by ← ENTER


  - Open terminal windows, and enter its settings.     
  


  - In settings set default behavior to start CMD.       
  


Now from folder where you are in, as you did before with keycombo, use Shift+F10,tap up arrow twice to select "Terminal"(letter T acts up on Win11),hold Shift+Ctrl+Enter, and viola, cmd runs from directory as whoever you enter in UAC.
Shift+Ctrl+T while in Terminal opens new tab(Ctrl+T does the same for explorer.exe ,if thats useful).

Is this for Windows11? I can't find these settings. The question is for Windows 10. Thanks again!

Indeed it is Windows 11.

Just checked on Win10,...just go to store and get "Windows terminal", you wont need arrows instead you can just use letter T(should work in Win11 with T, but acts up), rest is same.

@Danijel If you take screenshots of smaller windows, they will look much better in preview. Ideally 640x480px because the pictures are rendered 653px wide by default and it changes sometimes.

@Danijel On Win10, can we get "Windows terminal" somewhere else than from a store, just by downloading a .exe and installing it? (I don't like stores, I prefer good old .exe download and install)

Basj, MS has most of it somewhere like https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9n0dx20hk701 (downloads exe)
@cachius, didnt think that mattered too much, its snip oobe, rest is kind of a hassle

@Basj - No; Windows Terminal is only available on the Windows Store.

@Ramhound Well, no not rly ^^ https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases guys,...google,...wgr?

@Danijel - I omitted that particular fact purposely from my comment since I actually had the same thoughts that Windows Terminal could resolve the authors issue.
